# Smack API Streams to US Army Mil

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I am implementing an Android XMPP Client using smack API, when debuggig I have realized the following log. Does this mean that all streams are forwarded to us.army.mil host?

> stream:stream to="us.army.mil" xmlns

**Log**

```
12-30 10:21:25.622: D/MemorizingTrustManager(27860): checkCertTrusted: trying defaultTrustManager
12-30 10:21:25.832: D/SMACK(27860): SENT (0): <stream:stream to="us.army.mil" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
12-30 10:21:25.962: D/SMACK(27860): RCV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="testtims.turkcell.com.tr" id="505449b3" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
12-30 10:21:25.962: D/SMACK(27860): RCV (0): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
12-30 10:21:25.962: D/SMACK(27860): SENT (0): <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
12-30 10:21:26.042: D/SMACK(27860): RCV (0): <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
12-30 10:21:26.172: D/SMACK(27860): SENT (0): </stream:stream>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. I just means that Smack is trying to establish a connection to the XMPP service responsible for `us.army.mil`, because it's configured with the credentials of a user of this service.